# как мне прочитать .data файл на python

Tags: python, файлы

```
file = open("D:\\загрезки\\Skill.data", "r")
file.read()
file.close()
```

при запуске этого кода выводит такое сообщение в консоли:UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1804: character maps to . Как решить это?

Answer (score 3):

Это происходит потому что читая данные из файла он автоматически пытается преобразовать его в текст, что может вызвать ошибки когда .data файл содержит явно не только текст, но и ещё различные данные. Есть три выхода:

1. Чтение в виде байтов

   Вы можете прочитать файл в виде байтов никак их не интерпретируя, тем самым ошибок в процессе интерпретации байтов как текста не будет.

   ```
   file = open("path", 'rb')
   print(file.read())
   file.close()
   ```
2. Игнорирование ошибок

   Вы можете в процессе интерпретации игнорировать ошибки. Тем самым у вас получится строка которая, будет содержать вероятно месиво из символов.

   ```
   file = open("path", 'r', errors='ignore')
   print(file.read())
   file.close()
   ```

   P.s - у параметра error есть и другие значения помимо игнор, почитать о них вы можете [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers).
3. Установка нужной кодировки

   Если же вы всё же уверены что в .data файле содержится именно строка и ничто иное, вы можете попробовать установить другую кодировку. Какую именно - узнавать вам.

   ```
   file = open("path", 'r', encoding='ascii')
   print(file.read())
   file.close()
   ```

Comment: не помогло, перепробовал все ваши варианты, выводит все равно это: î♦d♀♥☺♦‼ÿ☺ÿ☺âÿ☺☺1¨ø☺♠îô☺ô☺ô☺∟♀d♦d

Comment: А что вы ожидали то?

Comment: Всё как раз таки работает, всё выводит. А то что вы пытаетесь по своему незнанию упорно прочитать файл который не содержит строк как 1 большую строку, так это исключительно ваши проблемы